# How to use `topics` as an argument in `getPastEvents()`

Tags: web3js, events

I am currently attempting to collect data on token transfers. In order to accomplish this, I am collecting data using `getPastEvents()` and I am passing a filter object as an argument to collect transfers between specific ethereum accounts:

```
let depositing_events = await contract.interface.getPastEvents('Transfer', 
                {
                    filter: {
                        from: from_address, 
                        to: to_address
                    }, 
                    fromBlock: first_block, 
                    toBlock:'latest' 
                }
            )
```

This has successfully worked for me for most tokens like USDT, however, it appears that I cannot use [filtered events with the BUSD token](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6e7a623c7c53#code). I suspect it has something to do with BUSD choosing to fire events in a non traditional manner. Considering that I cannot use `filter`, I instead want to use the `topic` option.

[Here is an example](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf8ce4c7a972ed6e87e1f6ef2c8f2fb0f1d50ce136c3984ff1797bc1e623f8067#eventlog) of a transaction of BUSD that led to topics of the event being exposed. What is the correct way to pass in the `topic` option into `getPastEvents` to filter for transactions between specific addresses.

Answer (score 2):

> `getPastEvents('Transfer', ...)`

There is no `event Transfer` in [the contract that you've linked](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6e7a623c7c53#code).

So this attempt will obviously not retrieve any information from the blockchain.

---

> BUSD choosing to fire events in a non traditional manner.

There is no such thing as "fire events in a non traditional manner".

Perhaps you meant to say "BUSD does not fire `Transfer` events".

---

> Here is an example of a transaction of BUSD that led to topics of the event being exposed.

First of all, every event has at least one topic, which is the hash of the event-signature itself.

Additional topics may follow, one for each indexed parameter in the event.

However, the event that you've linked is not a `Transfer` event.

How do I know?

Because its first topic is `0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925`,

while the first topic in a `Transfer` event would be:

```
const Web3 = require("Web3");
const topic0 = Web3.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)");
console.log(topic0); // 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
```

If you want to fetch events of [the type that you've linked](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf8ce4c7a972ed6e87e1f6ef2c8f2fb0f1d50ce136c3984ff1797bc1e623f8067#eventlog), then you can use `getPastLogs`, which is a "raw version" of `getPastEvents` (the latter simply takes the event-signature from the contract's ABI, and passes its hash to the former):

```
const depositing_events = await web3.eth.getPastLogs({
    address: "0x4fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6e7a623c7c53",
    topics: ["0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925"],
    fromBlock: first_block,
    toBlock: "latest"
});
```

---

As a side-note, when calling either `getPastLogs` or `getPastEvents`, I prefer to do it "in parts", because the node may fail to retrieve all events when there are too many of them.

For example:

```
async function getPastLogs(web3, address, topic0, fromBlock, toBlock) {
    if (fromBlock <= toBlock) {
        try {
            return await web3.eth.getPastLogs({
                address: address,
                topics: [topic0],
                fromBlock: fromBlock,
                toBlock: toBlock
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            const midBlock = (fromBlock + toBlock) >> 1;
            const arr1 = await getPastLogs(web3, address, topic0, fromBlock, midBlock);
            const arr2 = await getPastLogs(web3, address, topic0, midBlock + 1, toBlock);
            return [...arr1, ...arr2];
        }
    }
    return [];
}

...

async function someFunc() {
    const depositing_events = await getPastLogs(
        "0x4fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6e7a623c7c53",
        "0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925",
        first_block,
        await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
    );
    ...
}
```

Comment: I would hazard a guess that non-traditional means not ERC20 compliant...